# how to tkinter image to make the top layer

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the image. I have a text widget and a picture in the background. That is, the Text picture above the image. When I insert a new picture it becomes Above the text widget. And here I need some function to move the new image to the background and Text was in the foreground.

```
from tkinter import*

def listbox():
    def image_get(list_):
        global image_1
        if int(list_.curselection()[0]) == 0: #by clicking on the first item listbox
            image_1 = PhotoImage(file="4.png")
            lab = Label(root, image = image_1)
            lab.place(x=0, y=0)
            #root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)

    top = Toplevel(root)
    list_ = Listbox(top,width=20)

    list_.insert(END,'image 0','image 1','image 2','image 3','image 4','image 5', 'image 6','image 7','image 8','image 9')
    list_.pack()
    list_.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: image_get(list_) or top.destroy())


root = Tk()
root.minsize(1000,555)
root.maxsize(1000,555)
image_1 = PhotoImage(file="0.png")
lab = Label(root, image = image_1)
lab.place(x=0, y=0)
text=Text(root)
text.place(x=0,y=0)
king = Menu(root, postcommand=lambda: listbox())
root.config(menu=king)
view = Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
#view.add_command(label='Background',command=None)
king.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide some code. We need an example of what you have tried to work with. Have you tried anything? Take a look at this link: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to create a text widget in the listbox function and moved the text from the first widget to the second one that created in listbox function , but this method doesn't suit me. Because I am creating a text editor and there are a bunch of functions that are made for the first text widget and not for the second text widget that I created in the listbox function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order of placement. You are placing the label over the text box in your `image_get()` function. Instead you want to just update the label and the image will stay behind the textbox because we are not changing its potion and just changing the image.

The method you are using now just keeps adding new labels rather than updating the existing one.

Change this:

```
def image_get(list_):
        global image_1
        if int(list_.curselection()[0]) == 0: #by clicking on the first item listbox
            image_1 = PhotoImage(file="4.png")
            lab = Label(root, image = image_1)
            lab.place(x=0, y=0)
```

To this:

```
def image_get(list_):
        global image_1
        if int(list_.curselection()[0]) == 0: #by clicking on the first item listbox
            image_1 = PhotoImage(file="4.png")
            lab.config(image = image_1)
```

Comment: Thank. Thank you very much. I feel stupid. I'm so forgetful how could I forget about the config. Thank

Comment: It's ok. We all make some "obvious" mistakes. I made a silly one myself on a post Friday. Once you see it you think "how could I have missed it".